# JavaScript client-side validation vs Laravel server-side validation

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-validation

If I want to create the validation of a form, can I use jQuery alone or do I also have to create the validation on the PHP side?

jQuery validation is nicer

Comment: why not just make it for server and client side validation. jquery validation for a good UI and UX. there are also some validations that cannot be done by client side validation. it depends on what you need

Comment: Please do not tag-spam.  The jQuery Validate tag is meant for questions about this specific plugin.  Edited.  The question is also very broad and does not fit the standard for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

jQuery validation is front-end validation and is there to provide the user with a smooth experience and feedback on what they're entering. Because it all sits on the client's machine, they're able to mess with it as much as they want, so the validation isn't secure.

Laravel's validation is back-end validation and is there to make sure the data you're receiving is correct. Without back-end validation, malicious users are able to enter whatever they want into your program and can potentially cause harm.

tldr; front-end validation is important for user experience, back-end validation is important for security.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree implement on both.

But if you have to choose one to develop, definitely go for PHP validation (Back-end validation).

You can implement simple validation in HTML, example `required` for required field, `input type="email"` for email format validation, `input type="number"` for number format validation then pass to back-end for validation.

Front-end validation like jQuery validation can be by-pass when user disabled their javascript and it might pass fault data to back-end, that why back-end validation is much more important than front-end.

Back-end validation prevents you from potentially security leaks or recording of fault data.